# javascript regular expression of decimal value with minimum and maximum digits

Tags: javascript, regex

Can any one tell me the javascript regular expression of decimal value who validate the minimum 6 digits and maximum 15 digits after the decimal place. 
For Example its satisfied both 01.12345 and 01.000000000000000

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The regular expression:

`/^\d+\.\d{6,15}$/`

Should do it.

- `^` - From beginning of input
- `\d+` - One or more digits [0-9]
- `\.` - Decimal place
- `\d{6,15}` - Between 6 and 15 digits [0-9]
- `$` - To end of input

To test:

```
var regexp = /^\d+\.\d{6,15}$/;

var test = function (input, result) {
  if (regexp.test(input) === result) {
    console.log('OK');
  } else {
    console.error(input, result);
  }
}

test('0.0001', false);
test('12310.002301', true);
test('531412.135143613411552', true);
test('531412.1351436134115515', false);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try this regex

```
^\d+\.\d{6,15}$
```

**[REGEX DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/oL9kE8/35)**

Explanation:

```
\d{6,15} match a digit [0-9]
Quantifier: {6,15} Between 6 and 15 times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]
```